# SQL Server DateDiff

Tags: java, sql-server

I have a SQL Server query that I need to return all dates that are less that 90 days from the current. I thought this was quite trivial until the result set returned was completely wrong. Here's the query.

```
SELECT new_HwWarrantyEndDate 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE new_HwWarrantyEndDate IS NOT null 
  AND DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),new_HwWarrantyEndDate) <= 90;
```

Here are some of the results:

```
new_HwWarrantyEndDate
---------------------
2010-07-11
2012-12-09
2011-02-12
2012-12-09
2007-12-31
2007-12-31
2007-12-31
2007-12-31
```

How could this function return dates from years previous?

I have another issue.Why would a query such as:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),new_HwWarrantyEndDate) AS DateDiff 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE Diffdate IS NOT null;
```

Complain specifically DateDiff is not a valid column when I try and process the resultset ie:

```
result_set = stmt.executeQuery(query);
Date s;
if(!result_set.next()) {
System.out.println("Null set");
}
while(result_set.next()){
s = result_set.getDate("DateDiff");
System.out.println(s);
}
```

Thanks I don't have much experience with SQL Server. Any guidance would help.

Comment: Also (1) you can't reference an alias from the select clause in where, from, etc. (2) you named the alias datediff then tried to reference diffdate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [SARG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)able form;

```
SELECT new_HwWarrantyEndDate
FROM TABLE
WHERE  new_HwWarrantyEndDate IS NOT NULL
AND new_HwWarrantyEndDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(DAY, 90, GETDATE())
```

Comment: thanks buddy how is that different than dateAdd(day,getdate,90) ?

Comment: The function expects parameters as described in BOL (DATEADD (datepart , number , date )
)http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: Ahh! I thought I couldn't use DATEADD() BC it returns a date & I wasn't sure if sqlserver could compare dates in WHERE clause

Comment: That still gave me dates that were in 2015,2016 what worked for me was. `String query = "SELECT new_HwWarrantyEndDate FROM TABLE WHERE new_HwWarrantyEndDate IS NOT null AND"
       +" new_HwWarrantyEndDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(day,90,GETDATE());";`

Comment: I'm sooo sorry, my mistake! Didn't see that you wanted to look 90 days ahead - thought 90 days ago. Will edit my code now.